# Create string with variable names and values for data.table lookup

Tags: r, data.table, paste

I'm trying to construct a lookup string to match values in an R data.table.  Say I have a data.table called myDataTable with columns V1:V4 and a list called myList with 3 elements c("A", "B", "C").  Here's my (admittedly inelegant) code:

```
# create first value
matchstr <- paste('V1', '=="', myList[1], '"', sep="")

# construct rest of match string
for (i in 2:length(myList)) {
    matchstr <- paste(matchstr, ' & V', i, '=="', myList[i], '"', sep="")
}
matchstr <- paste(matchstr, ",", sep="")
```

My match string now looks like this:

```
matchstr
[1] "V1==\"A\" & V2==\"B\" & V3==\"C\","
```

If I use cat to output the string, it looks like this:

```
cat(matchstr)
V1=="A" & V2=="B" & V3=="C",
```

I want to use this as a lookup string for my data.table, like this:

```
myDataTable[V1=="A" & V2=="B" & V3=="C",]
```

If I do this with the text shown, I get the result I expect.  But if I try something like this:

```
myDataTable[matchstr]
```

I get

```
Error in `[.data.table`(wordTable, matchstr) : 
When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted,
and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take
advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.
```

If I try

```
myDataTable[cat(matchstr)]
```

I get

```
V1=="A" & V2=="B" & V3=="C",Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

How can I get this to work, preferably without the awkward string manipulation.
Thanks!

Comment: Set key on `V1,V2,V3` and then just do a binary search based subset. `setkey(DT, V1,V2,V3)` (or use `setkeyv`). Then `DT[mylist]` where `mylist = list("A", "B", "C")`.

Comment: Thanks @Arun, but that doesn't seem to do what I need. I tried setting the key based on columns V1:V3, but when I subset the data.table it only matches list items that occur in column V1.  So it found "A", "B", and "C" in column V1, not "A" in V1, "B" in V2, and "C" in V3.

Comment: Please edit your post with an example data.table, your list, and your code for us to reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a horrible way to go about this, but it can be done:

```
txt <- "V1==\"A\" & V2==\"B\" & V3==\"C\""
# note - i've removed the last comma from the end of the string

# example data:
set.seed(13)
dt <- data.table(replicate(3,sample(LETTERS[1:3],5,replace=TRUE)))
dt

#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  C  A  B
#2:  A  B  C
#3:  B  C  C
#4:  A  C  B
#5:  C  A  B

dt[eval(parse(text=txt))]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  A  B  C
```

Keep in mind:

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(106)
```

> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
>   -- Thomas Lumley
>         R-help (February 2005)

As @Arun notes, the preferred way would be to use more standard `data.table` functionality:

```
setkey(dt,V1,V2,V3)
mylist <- list("A", "B", "C")
dt[mylist]

#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  A  B  C
```

Comment: My god, that worked!  I'm still looking for a more elegant way to do this, but at least I now have a working model.  Thank you!